# Does Web sphere 8.5.5.2 support Spring boot applications

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, websphere-8

I am planning to use Spring Boot + Hibernate 4 in my next project. I have full WAS 8.5.5.2 server. Can any one suggest whether WAS 8.5.5.2 support Spring Boot 1.2 and Hibernate 4. Also if some one can point me to the step by step tutorial it would be great

Comment: Why wouldn't it... Just make it a deployable war and it should run.

Comment: It is not the task for WAS to support these but the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Boot is just Spring application. Since WAS can work with Spring + Hibernate application, there is no stops do not support Boot there as well. As Marten Deinum said above, you just need to make from your Boot app a deployable WAR and that's all. In addition you can get a gain from AS like WAS to get deal in your app with services from the container through the JNDI, e.g. JMS, DataSource, XA transactions etc... And Boot support JNDI for those resources well.

Comment: Thanks for the advise.. I got it working.. The combination of Spring boot + Hibernate and deployed successfully on WAS 8.5.5.2